# Evaluating double integral by polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

- $\displaystyle S$ is an area in the first quadrant in a Cartesius plane which is bounded by circle
  $\displaystyle x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$ and lines
  $\displaystyle y = 0$ and $\displaystyle x = 0$.
- Calculate $\displaystyle\iint\sin\left(\pi\left[x^{2} + y^{2}\right]\right)\,\mathrm{d}A$

I don't really understand the topic but I thought that we should convert it to polar coordinates and that's it; but then the area is also bounded by the lines
$\displaystyle x = y = 0$ so there must be something else.

Help me please, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I also don't understande which region is that. But if it turns out to be the region where $x,y\geqslant0$, then you should compute$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\int_0^1\sin(\pi\rho^2)\rho\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta$$because $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]\iff x,y\geqslant0$.

Comment: The specifiation of the domain is indeed weird, but the circle and the two lines delimit four bounded regions, all of which yield the same integral (of course the one you solved).

Comment: The question says "$S$ is an area in the *first* quadrant...". That's pretty clear to me

Comment: @Dylan You're right. I missed that.